# access the swiper classes in tailwind

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css, swiper.js, react-swiper

Is there any way to access the swiper classes in tailwind?

This is what the code on the page looks like:

```
<div class='swoper-wraper'>
  <li class='swiper-slide swiper-slide-visible swiper-slide-active'></li>
  <li class='swiper-slide swiper-slide-visible'></li>
  <li class='swiper-slide swiper-slide swiper-slide-visible swiper-slide-thumb-active'></li>
</div>
```

swiper code:

```
<div className='swiper-container'>
 <Swiper
   className='[&_swiper-slide]:opacity-70' //doesn't work
   modules={[Thumbs]}
   watchSlidesProgress={true}
   onSwiper={setThumbsSwiper}
 >
      //slides
 </Swiper>
</div>
```

I can't get access to swiper classes - `swiper-slide swiper-slide-visible swiper-slide-active`

```
 [&_swiper-slide]:opacity-70, [&>swiper-slide]:opacity-70 - doesn't work
 [&_li]:opacity-70 - work,
```

but i need swiper classes `swiper-slide-active` and `swiper-slide-thumb-active`

UPD: I also found that the file 'swiper/css/thumbs' is empty, there should be styles that I need. (

Answer (score 0):

you can try using @apply to access the swipper class

```
.swiper-slide-active{
@apply opacity-70
}
```

for more information
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/reusing-styles#extracting-classes-with-apply

Comment: Thank you. I tried it, it doesn't work.

Comment: @Lex2000 it does work but you most likely need to add !important:
```
.swiper-slide-active{
    @apply opacity-70
}
```
Or change the order of including your CSS files.

Comment: It worked in app.css of Laravel + Vue stack. Remember to declare :after pseudo classes for items like navigation buttons.